# Is there an iso standard for Currency Symbols?

Tags: currency, iso

I need to know the iso standard of Currency Symbols?
iso-4217 seems not covering this point.

Answer (score 4):

The ISO only covers the 3 letter currency codes, and not the extended symbols.

If you like to have all the symbols then you can check it out here: http://www.xe.com/symbols.php

Comment: not a standard, but a good list. The ISO standard does not cover icons, but Wikipedia has a good list too https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currency_symbol

Answer (score 0):

Not sure there is an ISO standard for currency symbols, e.g., £, $, etc. ISO-4217 is all about EUR, USD, GBP, etc. I guess this is the standard, as it is more consistent in how currency is shown and differentiates between currencies better.

Although not a standard, this may help: http://www.xe.com/symbols.php

Answer (score -4):

You can download the new ISO codes and Symbols with Unicode fonts from below link :

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5DVIZeIMrCQMGRYT3NFd05CSGM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Link has been removed.

Comment: It seems to be a link to a spreadsheet on a personal Google drive. Handy, but not authoritative with no details of its original source.

Comment: For istance, where is Yen ?